# How to create a new file in native folder with expo config plugins?

Tags: react-native, expo

As the title it is. with expo config plugin, I already figured out how to make changes on manifest, main activity and ... etc.

And Now I need to create some new activity files into the android folder (i am not sure if this is even possible) or there is some way could work around

The structure in android folder should looks like below

```
android
|-- app
|   |-- src
|   |   |-- main
|   |   |   |-- java/com/my/app
|   |   |   |    |-- [folder I want to create]
|   |   |   |    |   |-- [new activity files shall goes here]
|   |   |   |    |-- MainActivity.java
|   |   |   |    |-- MainApplication.java
```

Of course I could just apply the bare workflow and change the files directly inside of the native folder. However I would like to remaining use the managed workflow. so if there is any way I could archive this, will be nice!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The certain example could be found *[HERE](https://github.com/wodin/rn-hce-test/blob/395c1870acb9b9fbaec8349132af92d910a4d17d/plugins/withReactNativeHce.js#L110-L116)*

`dangerous mod` provide the tool for us to create folders or files.

### Example:

```js
import { withDangerousMod } from '@expo/config-plugins'

const wxapiAndroid: ConfigPlugin = (config) => {
  return withDangerousMod(config, [
    'android',
    async (config) => {
      const customePackageName = 'com.your_package.name'
      const srcPath = path.resolve(config.modRequest.projectRoot, config.modRequest.platformProjectRoot, `app/src/main/java/com/your/package_name`)
      //create a new file
      const newFileName = 'WXEntryActivity.java'
      const newFolderName = 'wxapi'
      const newFileContent = `
package ${customePackageName}.wxapi;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
public class WXEntryActivity extends Activity {
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    try {
      Intent intent = getIntent();
      Intent intentToBroadcast = new Intent();
      intentToBroadcast.setAction("com.hector.nativewechat.ACTION_REDIRECT_INTENT");
      intentToBroadcast.putExtra("intent", intent);
      sendBroadcast(intentToBroadcast);
      finish();
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
`
      const newFilePath = path.resolve(srcPath, newFolderName, newFileName)

      //create a new folder
      const newFolderPath = path.resolve(srcPath, newFolderName)
      if (!fs.existsSync(newFolderPath)) {
        fs.mkdirSync(newFolderPath)
      }

      //create a new file
      if (!fs.existsSync(newFilePath)) {
        fs.writeFileSync(newFilePath, newFileContent)
      }

      //create the pay api file
      const payApiFileName = 'WXPayEntryActivity.java'
      const payApiFileContent = `
        package ${customePackageName}.wxapi;
        import android.app.Activity;
        import android.os.Bundle;
        public class WXPayEntryActivity extends Activity {
            @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                
                finish();
            }
        }
        `

      const payApiFilePath = path.resolve(srcPath, newFolderName, payApiFileName)
      if (!fs.existsSync(payApiFilePath)) {
        fs.writeFileSync(payApiFilePath, payApiFileContent)
      }

      return config
    },
  ])
}

export default wxapiAndroid
```

Comment: This was extremely helpful, thanks for outlining your approach here! This worked like a charm, though it is truly dangerous.  I had tried to achieve this using [Expo modules](https://docs.expo.dev/modules/android-lifecycle-listeners/) but had no luck.