# Adding expo config plugins to existing native code

Tags: react-native, expo

This is my way to build a project,

1. Create a project with `npx create-expo-app MyApp -t`
2. I usually use `react-native-mmkv` for all my projects So I run `npx expo prebuild` and run `npx expo run:ios` to make it work.

But there is a confusion to me. There is a payment gateway called PayHere which has a react-native sdk but doesn't have expo plugins which means they don't support expo. Since I have built both iOS & android projects I can customize some native code as the payhere library has mentioned. So I do change in those both projects directly. But what if I need to install (after) a package which already has an expo plugin. So I add it to the app.json file and have to run this code again `npx expo prebuild` to apply changes to native code. But is this a good approach or a bad approach because I've already added some native code with my payment gateway which doesn't support expo. Will this break my existing code? I would really appreciate it if somebody can clear my doubts. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes and No( and is a bad approach ), according to the docs in expo `npx expo prebuild` will apply all plugins in to your native folder `ios` && `android` is not going remove the code you modified, but is really easy to break the changes when you do `prebuild`. usually is recommended to run `prebuild --clean` every time you changed any plugin.

---

my personal understand is, if you have any changes you need to do directly to both native folders, you should create your own `plugin`. then it will be safe to use `prebuild --clean` everytime.

PS. By what I say is easy to break the changes, you could check out the way how `expo plugin` works, if you changed any thing to the native folder there a huge possibility that some plugin won't work as expect, or if you run it for multiple time it will goes wrong, since you don't know how they implement all those change.

to have [my own question as an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77700676/how-to-create-a-new-file-in-native-folder-with-expo-config-plugins/77783686#77783686) if there any plugin is doing things with `withDangerousMod`（also there are many other method is also mark as `danger` you could [reference here](https://docs.expo.dev/config-plugins/plugins-and-mods/)) all those operates may course the problem when you do `pre-build`